# How to make responsive buttons in Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code for a button using Bootstrap:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">

     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Supplies

</button>
```

I would like the *Search Supplies* content to change to just *Search* for mobile users when resizing. How would I achieve this using jQuery and Bootstrap?

[Here's a jsbin of what I have so far](http://jsbin.com/jatomexaba/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Put12co22mer2's solution will work fine. But, if you want to set a specific screen size at which the "supplies" portion drops out, use CSS like this:

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width:/* Your specific width here */) {

    #supplies {

        display:none;

    }       

}
```

And this HTML:

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">

 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>    
 Search <span id="supplies">Supplies</span>

</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code did exactly what I needed :) - http://jsbin.com/bomekanila/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3):

Don't need jQuery :

Just wrap your word in a span with [`hidden-xs`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) class

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search <span class="hidden-xs">Supplies</span>

  </button>
```